# download part (one element) of a HTML page?

Tags: html, objective-c, web, download

Is it possible to only download one part of a webpage, so like one element and its sub elements. If it is how would you do it in objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what is usually done in AJAX calls. The page requests a page fragment from the server, the server spits it out via HTTP. It's really no different than serving up any other HTML.